# Finalize SQL query with joins and with search

Tags: php

I come here to ask for a little help please.
My goal is to get my list of categories in my page managements categories and also display beside the name of each category the number of articles published (statut 1) by category.
Without making a search, it works.
By cons, with a WHERE search keywords entered to display my list of categories according to keywords entered, or I can not.
with the code below, he tries to make the search in my table "articles", and not in my table "categories".
_I do not know how to make, where to put the LIKE in my request so that he makes the search in my table categories?
Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
* categories : Table of categories that can be connected to articles
* articles : Table of articles
* categories_jointes_articles : Pivot Table (which has a id_article fields and id_categorie)
*/
$sql = "SELECT categories.id, categories.nom
    , COUNT(articles.id) as nb_articles
    FROM categories
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories_jointes_articles
        ON categories.id = categories_jointes_articles.id_categorie

    LEFT OUTER JOIN articles
        ON articles.id = categories_jointes_articles.id_article
        WHERE articles.statut = ?
        OR statut IS NULL";

$sql .= " AND nom LIKE ? ";     // c'est cette ligne que je ne sais pas où mettre

$sql .= " GROUP BY categories.id, categories.nom";

$requete = self::getDb()->prepare($sql);

$requete->bindValue(1, 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$requete->bindValue(2, '%'.$mots.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$requete->execute();
$requete->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
return $requete;
```

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. However you haven't shown us what is in the `$mots` variable. Please give us an example of a value for this variable; this will help us find an answer for the question.

Comment: This is more an SQL question than a PHP question, so you should add the SQL tag. And when asking SQL questions you should also add a tag for the DBMS you are using, e.g. MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test.test_table VALUE(null, 'a XYZ name', 'a text', now())");
$sth->execute();
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM test.test_table WHERE test_name LIKE ?");
$search = "XYZ";
$sth->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

while($row = $sth->fetch()){
    echo $row->test_name."<br>";
}
```

Output:

a XYZ name

The above works on my end. Please try using both `$requete->bindParam` and `$requete->bindValue`. Both functions are different. You can revise your PHP to fit your need. Please kindly let me know your result.

What do your "getDb()" return? I assume that return a PDO handle.

Comment: sorry, I am not understood

Comment: Thank you. but it does not change

Comment: Totally wrong. The concatenated string in the question is identical to the enclosed string in your answer; PHP does not see any difference at all between them and changing it will have zero effect on the program.

Comment: Also, the "possible duplicate" you mentioned is an entirely different problem and not in any way relevant here. (in that question the problem was caused by poor understanding of string syntax)

Comment: This post is for Simba; why don't you provide some helpful tips than down-voting? Two of your vague and quick-to-mouth comments aren't that helpful to solving this poor man's problem. Please google before posting your helpless comments.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the search is done on `articles` instead of `categories`, so I assume that both tables have a column `nom`.

The DBMS should complain about ambiguity rather than deciding for one of the two columns and executing the query on a guess. I consider it a flaw when it doesn't.

As there are two tables with the same column name, you must qualify the column name with the table name, so as to show the DBMS which field you are talking about.

```
$sql .= " AND categories.nom LIKE ? ";
```

Moreover be aware that you are mixing `AND` and `OR`. `AND` has precedence over `OR` in SQL, so

```
WHERE articles.statut = ? OR statut IS NULL AND nom LIKE ?
```

equals

```
WHERE (articles.statut = ?) OR (statut IS NULL AND nom LIKE ?)
```

But you want

```
WHERE (articles.statut = ? OR statut IS NULL) AND nom LIKE ?
```

Hence:

```
        WHERE (articles.statut = ?
        OR statut IS NULL)";

$sql .= " AND categories.nom LIKE ? ";
```